Enterprise or enterprise - should I capitalize
When using the word enterprise as a substitute for company, should it be capitalized?  Such as "to benefit the enterprise".

You would not capitalise 'company' or 'enterprise' in a sentence of that type. Unlike German, English does not capitalise non-proper nouns.

You would capitalise "enterprise" only when it formed part of the name, such as "The London Enterprise Company".

It's usually not normal to capitalize, but sometimes in legal documents that relate to a specific enterprise, you might capitalize to indicate it is that specific enterprise you are talking about. Without more information in the question it's very hard to answer, though.

You capitalise proper nouns.  You don't capitalise the word "company" when it is not being used as part of a name.

I started a company with my wife and her brother.

If you are using "enterprise" as a synonym of "company" then you don't capitalise it.

This new enterprise will make lots of money.

However if the word "enterprise" or "enterprises" is part of a company name, then it would be capitalised:

Frost and Larkin Enterprises Ltd is an independent trading company.

